# How to check if a class has been declared in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Javascript has a convenient way to check if a class (or any other) exists in the global scope:

```
typeof SomeUndeclaredOne === 'undefined'
```

This method doesn't work in typescript because it produces a compilation error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SomeUndeclaredOne'
```

So my question is: what is the easiest way to check if a class exists in a typescript?
I'm looking for a generic way that works not only in browsers but also other environments (e.g. node.js or other environments that don't have a global object) and works with popular module systems (like ESModules, CommonJS) too.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: What usecase do you have for this in typescript?  As it is a strongly typed language, I would explicitly expect the compiler to throw up on all type errors at compile time rather then runtime.

Comment: The most obvious use of this is in typescript code, which has different behavior depending on the environment.
For example, I want to write a program that performs certain actions with the Buffer Node.js class, but still works in browsers (where there is no Buffer class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `declare` the class with TypeScript to get rid of the error.

```
declare class SomeUndeclaredOne {}
console.log(typeof SomeUndeclaredOne === "undefined")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the exact and complete answer to my question.